# Implementation of complementary filter and output of sensor while stationary

Tags: filter, output, gyro, python

The code for a complementary filtered angle is not outputting the expected angle.

I can get close to 90° using arctan formula from the accelerometer sensor data. Whereas, the complementary filter angle output is just around 1.717.

Also, I am not able to get 90° on the integrated gyroscope data.
So, can anyone help and check to see if I did implemented the complementary filter correctly or not?

```
def read_GyroscopeScaled (try_xAccelRotation, try_yAccelRotation):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x68, 0x43, 6)
    xGyro = data[0] * 256 + data[1]
    if xGyro > 32767 :
        xGyro -= 65536

    yGyro = data[2] * 256 + data[3]
    if yGyro > 32767 :
        yGyro -= 65536

    zGyro = data[4] * 256 + data[5]
    if zGyro > 32767 :
        zGyro -= 65536

    xGyroDPS = (xGyro - GyroxOff) / Gyro_scale
    yGyroDPS = (yGyro - GyroyOff) / Gyro_scale
    zGyroDPS = (zGyro - GyrozOff) / Gyro_scale    
    end_time = timeit.default_timer()
    current_time = end_time - start_time
    dt = current_time - previous_time
    xGyroAngle = xGyroAngle + xGyroDPS * dt
    yGyroAngle = yGyroAngle + yGyroDPS  * dt
    previous_time = current_time
    cfXangle2 = 0.98 * (cfXangle2 + xGyroAngle) + 0.02 * (xAccelRotation)
    cfYangle2 = 0.98 * (cfYangle2 + yGyroAngle) + 0.02 * (yAccelRotation)
    print ("X-Axis Degree per second : %.2f" %xGyroDPS)
    print ("Y-Axis Degree per second : %.2f" %yGyroDPS)
    print ("Z-Axis Degree per second : %.2f" %zGyroDPS)

n = 0
while n!=1:
    try_xAccelRotation, try_yAccelRotation, NetAcceleration = ADXL_read_AccelerometerScaled()
    read_GyroscopeScaled(try_xAccelRotation, try_yAccelRotation)
```

Comment: You are doing something really weird with your time measurements. Why do you care about the differences between how long it takes to acquire the data? Please explain.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the gyroscope data with the looping period in order to get the angle.

Comment: It seems to me that you should eliminate `end_time` and `current_time` and just calculate `dt = start_time - previous_time`.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be start_time - previous_time instead of end_time and current_time. I thought in order to get the time different between the last loop and the newest loop this is how i should get it done. As end_time is required for me to know when did the loop end, then i can use the ending time and subtract the starting time in order to know the total loop time.

Comment: Your code shows no loop at all. I have to assume that there's some other mechanism that calls this block of code repeatedly. Therefore, you need to take ONE reading of `timeit.default_timer()` and compare it to the `previous_time` that was set during the prior execution of the block. As it is, your `dt` is simply the difference between the execution time of some of the statements in your code, which should be very close to zero (unless there are interrupts, etc. going on at the same time).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code with the looping mechanism i am using which is a endless loop as i am required to get the data constantly. What i meant was, i thought we need a start time and end time then only it would be able to calculate the time used in the loop? According to your suggestion, all i need is just 1 timer, wouldn't it do not know when is the loop ends?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you -- your thinking is wrong!

Comment: Alright, i do not have access to it now but once i get access back i would definitely try it out. Thanks Dave!